# getting wrong solution to system of recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

i have been stuck on this question for hours now and would really appreciate any help. So i have the following system of recurrences
$$a_n=1+a_{n-1}, b_n = 1+b_{n-1}+2a_{n-1}, a_1=b_1=1, n\geq 2.$$
When i enter it into maple i get $$a_n=n,b_n=n^2$$ however when i try solving it using generator functions i keep getting $$a_n=n-1,b_n=(n+1)^2.$$ I would really appreciate if anyone could find where i am going wrong. My solution is below.

let $$A(Z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_nz^n, B(Z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}b_nz^n.$$
Then we would have $$\sum_{n \geq 1}a_nz^n = A(z)-1= \frac{1}{1-z}-1+zA(z).$$ i.e, $$A(z)-1=\frac{1}{1-z}-1+zA(z).$$ doing something similar for the other recurrence i got
$$B(z)-1 = \frac{1}{1-z}-1+zB(z)+2zA(z).$$ solving these two systems of linear equations i finally got  $$A(z)= \frac{1}{z^{2}-2 z+1},B = -\frac{z+1}{z^{3}-3 z^{2}+3 z-1}.$$
After this, i ask maple to give me A(z) in powerseries form and i get the following:
$$A(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)z^n.$$ Matching coefficients with $$A(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0}a_nz^n$$ i finally get the wrong answer:
$$a_n = n+1.$$
If anyone could find where i went wrong, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Both attempts $a_n = n-1$ and $a_n = n+1$ do not satisfy $a_1 = 1$. Can you check where you applied the initial condition?

Comment: @peterwhy sorry it only works for n>1. i'll add that in

Comment: When you wrote $\sum_{n \geq 1}a_nz^n = A(z)-1$, you were taking $a_0 = 1$. This does not work well with $a_1 = 1+a_0$.

Comment: @peterwhy in this case, is $a_0=0$ then? i thought $a_0$  always meant the initial condition.

Comment: But your question chose $a_1=1$ already, and then you have to calculate $a_0$ from the recurrence.

Comment: Or you may define a different function $A_2(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0}a_{n-1}z^n = a_1 + a_2z + a_3z^2 + \cdots$ with shifted indices, if you prefer to not define $a_0$.

Comment: @peterwhy But then you would have $a_{n-1}$. I think i would try the matrix approach. Generating functions don't seem to be working. thx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a matrix form will provide an enlightenment:

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n-1} \\ b_{n-1}
\end{Bmatrix}
+
\begin{Bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

From which, through repeated substitution, we can deduce that

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{1} \\ b_{1}
\end{Bmatrix}
+
\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{m}
\begin{Bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

The square matrix has a very interesting property:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{m}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2m & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore, the second equation becomes

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2n-2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{1} \\ b_{1}
\end{Bmatrix}
+
\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 2m & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
1 \\ 1
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Substituting $a_{1}=b_{1}=1$ we get the following:

$$
\begin{aligned}
a_{n}&=n \\
b_{n}&=n^{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you. i will try this method of solving them

Answer (score 0):

The desired solutions can be developed very quickly by induction. Thus,

$$
\begin{align}
&a(1)=1\\
&a(2)=a(1)+1=2\\
&a(3)=a(2)+1=3\\
&\vdots\\
&a(n)=a(n-1)+1=n
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
&b(1)=1\\
&b(2)=b(1)+1+2a(1)=4\\
&b(3)=b(2)+1+2a(2)=9\\
&b(4)=b(3)+1+2a(3)=16\\
&\vdots\\
&b(n)=b(n-1)+1+2a(n-1)=n^2
\end{align}
$$